# What does Wayne Enterprises produce in the Batman comics?

Tags: comics, dc, batman

In the new Batman movies Wayne Enterprises produces military weapons but what does it produce in the comic book? I'm not a big comic book reader but I am curious.

If there is canon evidence please provide.

Comment: I would assume it's more of the same. How else can they hand-wave the technology that batman gets a hold of over the years?

Comment: Justice.​​​​​​​

Answer (score 12):

#### [Wayne Enterprises](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Wayne_Enterprises) is a multi-layered conglomerate covering a wide range of industries and technologies. It also helps to fund and support the Thomas and Martha Wayne Foundations.

- While separate parts of the company are mentioned from time to time depending on the media it's depicted in, the conglomerate appears to have sufficient fingers to support pretty much whatever Bruce Wayne and Batman needs after it vanishes off the back of a truck or cargo vessel or warehouse and is appropriated for Batman's development and use.
- The conglomerate has fingers in at least six separate industries including food, shipping, naval shipyards, research and large-scale industrial manufacturing, medical research and technology, advanced electronics development and manufacturing and entertainment, news and media.

> - WayneCorp continues to achieve excellence across a wide range of industry sectors and markets, employing some 170,000 people in 170 countries. The current CEO and Chairman, Bruce Wayne, is a keen modernizer and continues to grow the business in the financial sector and in high-end technologies.
> - Bruce Wayne maintains a 51% majority ownership/control of the common stock, as the controlling stockholder of Wayne Enterprises. This allows for the prevention of any hostile takeover attempts of the company by a corporate raider or nefarious individual, attempting to seek control of the vast Wayne empire.
> - Another 30% of the common stock is in friendly hands of allies of Bruce Wayne. Therefore, any hostile takeover attempts of Wayne Enterprises would be unlikely. The company is the eighth largest international conglomerate in the DC universe.

- Forbes Magazine estimated that Wayne Enterprises revenues would be approximately $31 billion dollars and ranked number 11 in the top richest fictional corporations. [-- The Top 25 Richest Fictional Corporations](http://www.forbes.com/sites/michaelnoer/2011/03/11/the-25-largest-fictional-companies/)

[image]

Comment: Large chunks of this seem to be based on the wiki. I'm not doubting the answer but can you offer any source material?

Comment: Batman isn't supplied by what falls off of trucks or goes missing, at least not any more. Give a lookup to Batman, Incorporated.

Comment: That was a joke. In the comics, Batman just took what he needed and turned it into Bat-Stuff. In Batman Inc, Bruce Wayne all but says, I am Batman.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't comprehensive (yet), but here's a small, new 52 look at some of what Wayne Enterprises does, from the mouth of Lucius Fox (Batman #25):

[image: batman 25]

[image: batman 25]

I don't have my copy of City of Owls handy, but Batman Annual #1 is also instructive as we get a look at what Victor Fries was doing for Wayne before he went (more) crazy (hint: started in cryonics).

Here's some additional info from Batman #21, from Bruce's uncle, Philip Kane:

[image: batman 21]